# jqGrid setSelection not highlighting row onload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am passing MVC model to view, populating a hidden field with an `ID`, then I need the corresponding row to highlight to show selection.

I have tried `setSelection` in various ways, none are working.  No errors.  Here are the things I have tried:

```
$("#computer-grid").jqGrid("setSelection", "3");
```

or

```
var hardwareId = $("#HardwareId").val();
$("#computer-grid").jqGrid("setSelection", hardwareId);
```

and in the `loadComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $("computer-grid").setSelection(hardwareId, true);
}
```

and in `loadComplete` calling an outside function:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    showSelectedRow();
}


function showSelectedRow() {
    var hardwareId = $("#HardwareId").val();
    $("computer-grid").setSelection(hardwareId, false);
}
```

I don't have to use `setSelection` if there is another option.  I just want the the grid row to be highlighted of the `hardwareId` is not null.

/////EDIT///////
Additional info as requested:

I am using jqGrid  4.8.2 which I downloaded from trirand.com.
I have 2 grids on the page.

```
    var computerGridUrl = $("#CpuFunctionUrl").val();   //window.GetCpuGridUrl();
    var mobileGridUrl = $("#MobileFunctionUrl").val();  //window.GetMobileGridUrl();

    $("#computer-grid").jqGrid({

        url: computerGridUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Id', 'Type', 'Model', 'Description', 'Price'],
        colModel: [
                { name: "HardwareId", key: true, hidden: true },
                { name: "ItemType", sortable: true},
                { name: "Model", sortable: true },
                { name: "ItemDescription", width: 400 },
                { name: "Price", formatter: "currency", align: "center", sortable: true }
        ],
        loadonce: true,
        height: '200',
        autowidth: true, 
        pager: "#cpu-grid-pager",
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            SetDeviceId(id);
            UnSelectRow("#mobile-grid");
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            showSelectedRow();
        }
    });

    $("#mobile-grid").jqGrid({

        url: mobileGridUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Id', 'Type', 'Model', 'Description', 'Price'],
        colModel: [
                { name: "HardwareId", key: true, hidden: true },
                { name: "ItemType" },
                { name: "Model", sortable: true},
                { name: "ItemDescription", width: 400 },
                { name: "Price", formatter: "currency", align: "center" }
        ],
        loadonce: true,
        height: '200',
        autowidth: true,
        pager: "#mobile-grid-pager",
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            SetDeviceId(id);
            UnSelectRow("#computer-grid");
        }
    });

function SetDeviceId(id) {
    var deviceId = id;
    if (deviceId > 0) {
        $("#SelectedDevice").val(deviceId);
    }
}

function UnSelectRow(gridName)
{
    $(gridName).jqGrid("resetSelection");
}

function showSelectedRow() {
    var hardwareId = $("#HardwareId").val();
    $("computer-grid").setSelection(hardwareId);
}
```

/////////////////SECOND EDIT - add json string response /////////////////

This is the initial data load to populate the grid:

```
[{"HardwareId":1,"Model":"Latitude 14 7000","ItemDescription":"lightweight mobile computer","ItemType":"Lightweight Laptop","IsMobile":false,"IsMiFi":false,"Price":1254.00,"CellularPlan":null,"AppStoreId":null,"SelectedDevice":0,"RequestId":0},{"HardwareId":2,"Model":"Latitude E6540","ItemDescription":"A mobile computer","ItemType":"Standard Laptop","IsMobile":false,"IsMiFi":false,"Price":2096.00,"CellularPlan":null,"AppStoreId":null,"SelectedDevice":0,"RequestId":0},.....]
```

Once the user selects a row, the rowid is saved to the "SelectedDevice" hidden field, which is within a FORM that is then submitted to the server. The grids are not within the form.  All that is working fine.

What I am doing now is handling what happens if the user comes back to this page.  This web application has 6 views with a form on each page, kind of like a wizard.  If the user comes back to this page the the grids, the server sends the HardwareId, which is then stored in a hidden field '#HardwareId'.  What I am attempting now is, when the grids populate, it should then look for a value in the HardwareId hidden field, and if there is one, it should highlight the corresponding row in the grid.

So after the user clicks the back button, this hidden field gets a value:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HardwareId must be a number." data-val-required="The HardwareId field is required." id="HardwareId" name="HardwareId" type="hidden" value="4" />
```

Comment: Could you include more detailed information: which jqGrid version and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) oder an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use? Could you include an example of at least one item of data returned from the server (especially `id`), at least the following options of jqGrid: `datatype`, `colModel` (especially `id` column), `multiselect`, `jsonReader`, `loadonce` and `prmNames`. If you use free jqGrid, for example, you can use `multiPageSelection: true`

Comment: I have added some more information as requested.  I'm not sure what you need to know onthe data returned from the server?  The initial grid population is It is using the MVC 'JsonResult', so I believe it is a json string.   However, the hidden field with the hardwareid is passed with the usual MVC model to the view from the controller.  The only time this would be populated is if the user had made a selection, moved on, then come back with the back button.

Comment: You have the problem with the rowid. Could you include an example of the server response (with two rows of data)? Where are `HardwareId` values in the input data?

Comment: What are the elements `#HardwareId"`` and `#SelectedDevice`. You should include `idPrefix` paremeter for at least one grid to be sure that you have no id duplicates on the page. Moreover I'd recommend you to try to replace URLs to jqGrid files (at least for the test) to the URLs of free jqGrid 4.13.0 described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)

Comment: You should write short comment to inform other about the changes of the text of your question. I opened your old question absolutely accidentally. You included example of JSON response. Is it the data for the first or the second grid (from `mobileGridUrl` or from `computerGridUrl`)? It seems that you have two grids with absolutely **the same** `colModel` and probably with the same data. The values `HardwareId` are the same as `id` of `<tr>` and there **could be the same** in both grids and id duplicates can be. Moreover you calls `UnSelectRow` inside of `onSelectRow`, which is very suspected.

Comment: There are two grids on the same page, they are structured the same, but contain different data. The unSelectRow is in the onSelectRow because the user is only allowed to select one item from one grid.  The two grids contain lists of computer hardware that a user may request.  The computer-grid is populated with desktop computers, the mobile-grid is populated with tablets and phones.  A user may only select one device per request.  Are you able to tell me why the setSelection method is not working?

Comment: Is the JSON data, which you included, are for the first (from `computerGridUrl`) or the second grid (from `mobileGridUrl`)? Can the same items (with `"HardwareId":3`) in both grids? Could you provide the demo which demonstrates the problem? You can use Echo server of JSFiddle like in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/37rb593h/4/ to simulate returning the data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some of these should have worked, not sure why.  I noticed some of my examples where missing the pound (#) in the grid id call, which led to this working code:

Inside the grid definition:

```
        loadComplete: function () {
            showSelectedRow();
        }
```

Then the function:

```
function showSelectedRow() {
    var hardwareId = $("#HardwareId").val();
    $("#computer-grid").jqGrid('setSelection', hardwareId);
}
```

Working now.